# How to Electron video framerate forcibly lower

Tags: javascript, electron

I am currently working on a project where I need to publish WebRTC video.
But our server is poor, so I want video framerate forcibly lower.

Electron's framerate is 60fps as default, but I thought it would work video getUserMedia() constraint.

I tried like this:

```js
constraints = { video: { frameRate: { ideal: 15, max: 15 } } };
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: i want to publish 15fps video. but we can watch 60fps video only. It's so heavy data.

Comment: Please provide more information as to what is happening vs what you are trying to achieve. The MDN Docs about WebRTC state that this is the correct way to do it, so what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you. Check it out.